# Visual Studio 2015 cannot create Release builds for Cordova project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for Cordova Tools to build an app that targets Windows Universal (UWP) and Android.

I can successfully create **Debug** builds for both Android and UWP, Release build works for Android as well.

However Visual Studio fails to create **Release** builds for UWP, none of the `Windows-AnyCPU`, `Windows x86`, `Windows x64` and `Windows ARM` options works.

When creating **Release** builds for `Windows-AnyCPU`, the error message is like:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(133,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2, Version=1.2". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". [C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(133,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1, Version=1.1". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". [C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(248,5): error MSB4062: The "IlcErrorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\ilc.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\ilc.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\msbuild with args: C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=release,/p:Platform=anycpu
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat" --release "--buildConfig=C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\build.json" --archs=anycpu --win"
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

When creating **Release** builds for `Windows x86`, `Windows x64` or `Windows ARM`, the error message is like:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(669,5): error MSB4062: The "SharedAssemblyApplicabilityVerifierTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\ilc.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\ilc.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(405,5): error MSB4062: The "ComputeManagedBinaries" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\ilc.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\ilc.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\msbuild with args: C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=release,/p:Platform=x64
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat" --release "--buildConfig=C:\Users\ztl87\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\UnihanHelper\UnihanHelper\build.json" --archs=x64 --win"
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

What confuses me is that all of these 4 configurations works fine with **Debug** builds.

---

**Moreover**, Visual Studio stops working when I try to associate the app with the Windows Store.

I am using:

- Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova 14.0.51016.1
- Cordova CLI version
  5.4.1

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent hours struggling with this and was able to solve it finally by uninstalling Node 64 bit and installing 32 bit.

Comment: Sure... wish I could be more clear as to why it worked.  I just noticed that MSBuild was 32bit and I've heard a lot of bad things about Node 64bit not playing well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me some time

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the architecture and the platform you want to build the Windows app in.

```
cordova build --release windows --appx=[platform] --archs=[architecture]
```

Options:

- Platform: 8.1-win, 8.1-phone, uap
- Architecture: x86, x64, arm

For Example:

```
cordova build --release windows --appx=uap --archs=arm
```

Reference: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/

Comment: Thanks! The `--arch` switch works as intended. I don't understand why this isn't documented (it doesn't even show when using the `--help` switch).

Comment: I dont know either. I found it when I was looking at the source code in the CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj file

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio stops working when I try to associate the app with the Windows Store.

This is a bug that has just been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Here's a link to the installer: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129